# Cannot install python3.6 on google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, google-colaboratory, virtualenv

I am unable to install Python 3.6 on Google Colab. I saw a few previous posts where others were able to install the same version. I am, however, able to install Python 3.7. I ran the following commands from [how to use python 3.6 in google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581774/how-to-use-python-3-6-in-google-colab).

```
# first install python 3.6
!sudo apt-get update -y
!sudo apt-get install python3.6
# change alternatives
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
# select python version
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
# check python version
!python --version
# install pip for new python 
!sudo apt-get install python3.6-distutils
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
!python get-pip.py
# upgrade pip
!sudo apt install python3-pip
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

[image: Console screenshot]

Any workarounds for installing Python 3.6 and setting up a virtual environment in Google Colab would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want 3.6?

Comment: You should not be installing Python 3.6 in the first place, since it has been unsupported for more than 4 years. You will have an extremely bad time trying to get anything modern to work on it.

Comment: @KellyBundy https://endoflife.date/python (you'll need to expand the table to see ancient relics)

Comment: @KellyBundy In the "Security support" column, yes. The "Active support" column says "Ended 4 years and 10 months ago (24 Dec 2018)".

Comment: @AKX (I didn't know earlier, I had checked [Python's own page](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) which disagrees. Anyway, cleaning up my comments...)